# htaccess remove matched word from url and redirect 301

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

I have site and it had urls like this

```
www.familiehunden.no/hundekurs/valpekurs.html
```

I did some updates to site and now the urls like this

```
www.familiehunden.no/valpekurs.html
```

hundekurs is a category, i have this kind of categories, i need to redirect old urls to new urls without getting 404 error as now. can anyone help me, i tried using this but no luck

```
www.familiehunden.no/hundekurs/* --> www.familiehunden.no/ ?
```

this is an joomla site

thank you verymuch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^hundekurs/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(folder1|folder2)/.*$
RewriteRule .*/(.*)\.html $1\.html [R=301]
```

The first line can be removed for you. But I guess not EVERY directory should be redirected.

In that case fill in the pipe (|) seperated list with directories that should not be redirected.

If every folder should be redirected, just remove the first line.

Comment: thanks hundekurs is not an folder it is something like category
is that ok to use this sir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(hundekurs)/.*$
RewriteRule .*/(.*)\.html $1\.html [R=301]

Comment: It isn't really a folder indeed. You should not fill in categories in the first line. Fill in only "folders" that should NOT redirect. If your joomla website has for example some contact pages like domain.com/contact/page1.html, you should insert "contact" in the first line to not redirect the contact pages.